# making named pipes and using poll

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

I'm so confused with this, I need to create named pipes using mkfifo (i know how to do this) the program before would use fork to create child processes that would do something, but now I have to replace fork with poll() to watch multiple streams (that's the part I don't get). In more detailed, when i run my program in terminal, its suppose to make the mkfifo files and then wait till a stream comes in, hence just stay there, not closing. Then I open up a new terminal, and need to input exactly this into terminal "cat file1 > (name of the mkfifo files)" and what that should do is make the program read the data that was in file1, on any of the input pipes made from mkfifo. I've looked everywhere but can never put things together to make it work.

this is what i have so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "battleFieldReader.h"   //this is where all the data computation is done 

main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (sscanf (argv[1], "%i", &N) !=1 )
    {
        printf ("ERROR: Please input an integer.\n");
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    struct pollfd pfd[2];
    pid = getpid();
    printf("pid=%d\n",pid);
    N = atoi(argv[1]);
    signal(SIGTERM, removePipes);
    int i;
        char fileName[32];
        char fileName2[32];
        snprintf (fileName, sizeof(fileName), "%d_%di", pid, 0);
        mkfifo(fileName, 0666);
        pfd[0].fd = open(fileName, O_RDONLY | O_NDELAY);
        pfd[0].events = POLLIN;

        snprintf (fileName2, sizeof(fileName2), "%d_%do", pid, 0);
        mkfifo(fileName2, 0666);
        pfd[1].fd = open(fileName2, O_WRONLY | O_NDELAY);
        pfd[1].events = POLLIN;

    while(1)
    {
        int n;
        n = poll(pfd, 2, 3000);
        if(n < 1)
        {
            printf("waiting...\n");
            continue;
        }

        if(pfd[0].revents & POLLIN)
        {
            printf("test\n");
/*ideally this is where i would put a method to compute data but its just an infinite loop, its suppose to stop, so it can do the same thing whenever another file comes on, but I dont know how to stop it either*/
        }
    }
}
```

whats happening is I'm creating a pipe 2N times, one for input and output for whatever process id is running the program. then wait till something comes in on one of the pipes and then spit out what needs to be done with the file data. Can anyone clear things with me, if I'm going in the right direction or something.

Comment: Did you read [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) and [fifo(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fifo.7.html) before coding? Then read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) ...

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes on the pipe and fifo, but that book seems like it will help even more help, thank you

Answer (score 1):

`poll` tells you if you can read from or write to a file descriptor without blocking (or without getting an EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK result if the fd in non-blocking).

Your code has a number of obvious problems:

- You say you want to create 2N fifos, but then you only create 2.  Your `pfd` array has a fixed size of 2, too.  You'll need a bigger array and loop to create more.
- You open an `O_WRONLY` file descriptor to write to a pipe, but then you set the `events` field to `POLLIN`, which will test for input available.  You want `POLLOUT` to test for output possible.
- In your processing loop, you poll two fds, but you only check `pfd[0]` for availability, and then you never do anything with it.  You should read `pfd[0].fd` after the `pfd[0].revents & POLLIN` check succeeds.  You should also check `pfd[1].revents & POLLOUT` and write data to `pfd[1].fd` if that succeeds.

Comment: Yea i intentionally left all that stuff out, I wasn't getting it correctly by making a loop with doing it N times, so i was just working with 1 at a time, but i didnt see the POLLOUT, but what i dont get is, if i put a method (inside the input descriptor statement) thats in the header file, it crashes.

Comment: @StevenR: That sounds like it has nothing to do with the polling and the named pipes and everything to do with the code you are calling that crashes.  Perhaps it doesn't work properly with non-blocking file descriptors?

Comment: No the method works, because i ran it seperatly on another program, the same exact way, and it worked.

Comment: @StevenR: Obviously not if it crashes now -- it clearly can't be *exactly* the same.  There must be something different between the two cases.  Where the crash occurs is where to start looking.

Comment: The crash happens whenever I enter the while loop and wait for something to happen, i guess i just dont understand this whole polling thing at all. and yes the method works, because we had to ensure that the method works before implementing it here

Comment: What do you mean "when you enter the while loop"?  Can't be on the `while(1)` itself, as that is just a label.  Use a debugger to see exactly where it is crashing -- which specific machine instruction -- and figure out what is wrong that causes that instruction to crash.